# C++ Library Compatibility

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, binary-compatibility

I am currently writing a library and am considering moving from GCC 4.1.2 to 4.5.2 (latest release) of GCC. If I compile my code into a static library can I assume compiler compatibility (on the same OS obviously) should be a non-issue for clients?

**EDIT**
To further clarify: if I provide a client a statically linked library compiled with gcc 4.5.2, what restrictions does this place on users of this library in terms of the compiler and version they must use?

Comment: If I understood your question right..then yes.

Comment: I've clarified my question, see Edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just came across this which I believe answers my question from http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#nonbugs:

> ABI changes The C++ application binary
>   interface (ABI) consists of two
>   components: the first defines how the
>   elements of classes are laid out, how
>   functions are called, how function
>   names are mangled, etc; the second
>   part deals with the internals of the
>   objects in libstdc++. Although we
>   strive for a non-changing ABI, so far
>   we have had to modify it with each
>   major release. If you change your
>   compiler to a different major release
>   you must recompile all libraries that
>   contain C++ code. If you fail to do so
>   you risk getting linker errors or
>   malfunctioning programs. Some of our
>   Java support libraries also contain
>   C++ code, so you might want to
>   recompile all libraries to be safe. It
>   should not be necessary to recompile
>   if you have changed to a bug-fix
>   release of the same version of the
>   compiler; bug-fix releases are careful
>   to avoid ABI changes. See also the
>   compatibility section of the GCC
>   manual.
>
> Remark: A major release is designated
>   by a change to the first or second
>   component of the two- or three-part
>   version number. A minor (bug-fix)
>   release is designated by a change to
>   the third component only. Thus GCC 3.2
>   and 3.3 are major releases, while
>   3.3.1 and 3.3.2 are bug-fix releases for GCC 3.3. With the 3.4 series we
>   are introducing a new naming scheme;
>   the first release of this series is
>   3.4.0 instead of just 3.4.

From this as I understand it I'll need to ensure clients are linking my library in with a major-release compatable version of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if you are providing a static library or dynamic library, the users will still need to use a compatable compiler/linker to link against it. Usually when GCC does a ABI change they offer a switch that can be set to use the old ABI. I know that they did that when they went from 3.x to 4.x and even a couple of the releases within the 4.x series.